# How to prove that $DK=DL$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

[image]

In $\triangle ABC$ the cevians $AD$,$BE$ and $CF$ are concurrent at the point $O$. $DL\parallel  EF$ and $BE$ intersects $DL$ at $K$. How to prove that $DK = DL$.
I applied menelaus theorem twice in the $\triangle KEL$ and got a relation $\frac{DL^2} {DK^2}=\frac{BE} {BK}\cdot \frac{CL} {CE} \cdot \frac{AL} {AE} \cdot \frac{EO} {KO}$ and also  tried to use the ratio of similar triangles but no result. any ideas  on utilizing the ratio of similar triangles.

Comment: Please vote to undelete https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737508/how-to-prove-that-in-every-triangle-the-segment-oj-kl/3776921#3776921

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following timon92, we are going to prove $\dfrac{DA}{AJ}=\dfrac{DO}{OJ}$.

[image]

Consider the figure (only add point $M$, which is an intersection of lines $EF$ and $BC$), we focus on $\triangle MDJ$, and apply Menelaus's theorem 4 times:
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\frac{MB}{BD}}\color{red}{\frac{DA}{AJ}}\frac{JF}{FM}&=1;\tag{1}\\
\color{blue}{\frac{MB}{BD}}\color{orange}{\frac{DO}{OJ}}\color{green}{\frac{JE}{EM}}&=1;\tag{2}\\
\color{purple}{\frac{MC}{CD}}\color{orange}{\frac{DO}{OJ}}\frac{JF}{FM}&=1;\tag{3}\\
\color{purple}{\frac{MC}{CD}}\color{red}{\frac{DA}{AJ}}\color{green}{\frac{JE}{EM}}&=1.\tag{4}
\end{align}
Combining (1) and (4), and combining (2) and (3), respectively, we obtain
\begin{align}
\left(\color{red}{\frac{DA}{AJ}}\right)^2
=\left(\color{blue}{\frac{MB}{BD}}\frac{JF}{FM}\color{purple}{\frac{MC}{CD}}\color{green}{\frac{JE}{EM}}\right)^{-1}
=\left(\color{orange}{\frac{DO}{OJ}}\right)^2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You may want to start like this: Since $EF \parallel DL$, we have $\dfrac{DL}{JE}=\dfrac{DA}{AJ}$ and $\dfrac{DK}{JE} = \dfrac{DO}{OJ}$. The problem reduces to showing that $\dfrac{DA}{AJ}=\dfrac{DO}{OJ}$.